# Implementing a Typescript map types for parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to enforce the arguments with custom mapped types, and currently, it seems to be working fine but few pitfalls in the implementation as listed below.

- The type checking for sub-property seems doesn't to work as an example if I change the value of `enableDomain` to string it doesn't give an error.
- Cannot iterate the keys of the object as it returns the type of `ObjectValuesOf`
- Is there a better way to do it?

```js
// Types source
const OperatorConfigs = {
  certManager: {
    namespace: 'cert-manager',
    enableDomain: true
  },
  contour: {
    namespace: 'contour',
  }
} as const


// Types
type ObjectKeyOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: unknown }
type ObjectValuesOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: ObjectKeyOf<T[K]> }
type OperatorKeysUnion<
  T,
> = T extends {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] | object
} ? ObjectValuesOf<T>
  : never
type OperatorOptions = OperatorKeysUnion<typeof OperatorConfigs>


// Interface
export interface OperatorArgs {
  namespace?: string;
  operators?: OperatorOptions;
}
```

Expected output for `OperatorOptions` is as below

```
type OperatorOptions = {
    certManager?: {
        namespace?: string;
        enableDomain?: boolean;
    };
    contour?: {
        namespace?: string;
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code results in the object where the values are unknown, thus type-checking doesn't work. Check [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjaalW). Can you include what is expected shape of the `OperatorOptions`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqpyQN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does partially work, just the part like 'namespace' as an example it doesn't check the type since it became typeof `unknown`

Comment: namespace is string or undefined. Where is it unknown?

Comment: I mean if you put boolean it still accept it.

Comment: I see error [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxJqGw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is convert the literal types to their primitives:

```
1     -> number
'str' -> string
[1]   -> number[]
```

Let's use [ToPrimitive](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/to-primitive.d.ts?plain=1#L13), defined in the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/) package. We will slightly modify it to make the fields of objects and arrays not `readonly` :

```
type ToPrimitive<T> = T extends string
  ? string
  : T extends number
  ? number
  : T extends null
  ? null
  : T extends undefined
  ? undefined
  : T extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : T extends bigint
  ? bigint
  : T extends symbol
  ? symbol
  : {
      -readonly [K in keyof T]: ToPrimitive<T[K]>;
    };
```

It works since every literal type is a `subset` of the general type:

```
// true
type Case1 = 1 extends number ? true : false
// false
type Case2 = number extends 1 ? true : false
```

Additionally, to make the output type more readable we will use [Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15):

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
// type OperatorOptions = {
//   certManager?:
//     | {
//         namespace?: string | undefined;
//         enableDomain?: boolean | undefined;
//       }
//     | undefined;
//   contour?:
//     | {
//         namespace?: string | undefined;
//       }
//     | undefined;
// };
type OperatorOptions = Prettify<ToPrimitive<typeof OperatorConfigs>>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMGdTwPYFcBOBjWAoTyA7eAF1AHk50BDY5dAYUIDMBLAc0QF5QBvHUUNnTEAslQJU2sdAC5e-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-jJMfCklK08SBNATdtwhChpEg9BoJYWDYT3A8WCPE95w+L5vh3d8LOoWgGGYdh4D+NcCmOABJIZpCYYjRVWcVhEHNoouwcDLN8gBBPpEAfFSYhIkk9VBX9kAg3z4FI7yrJs2D8gpIA)